# wp_footer(); called before body but W3 Total Cache shows an error

Tags: php, wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have installed in my site the W3 Total Cache plugin, and lately this error appeared:

> Your active theme:
>
> · Has the call to  but it is not called directly before the closing body tag

This is the end of my footer.php archive:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';      ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :  'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')     [0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();
</script>

 <?php wp_footer(); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see `wp_footer();` is immediately before the `</body>` tag. Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to interfere with the "codehorse"'s answer, but still:

wp_footer() is a function  which should be above , [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) clearly states "Put this template tag immediately before  tag in a theme template (ex. footer.php, index.php)".

In my humble opinion, the right code will be this one:

```
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Here goes your Google analytics code
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

So, as you see. "wp_footer" goes above your Ganalytics code, in this case nothing will get messed up. There are even small WP plugins specifically for inserting Google analytics, but it's for lazy people, hehe

Comment: You shouldn't call `<script>` tags directly in WordPress; use the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function instead.  Also, wrap any HTML tags (like `</body>`) in backticks (`\``) so they will be visible in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a neat way, and safe. The only reason for inserting JS directly into a WP file is that it can be done quickly, and it rarely causes any issues. In this case with "codehorse" question, i tried to answered in a simplest way possible.

Anyway, thanks for this note, it might be helpful for those who didn't know about it.

Comment: True. But there's a proper way to enqueue JS files (and CSS files for that matter), and you might as well do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `<script>` tags directly in WordPress.  Instead, use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script):

`google-analytics.js`

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';      ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :  'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')     [0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();
```

Then, in your theme's `functions.php` file or a plugin file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so20272587_add_analytics' );
function so20272587_add_analytics() {
    $handle = 'google-analytics';
    $src = 'path/to/google-analytics.js'; // where your JS file lives
    $deps = array(); // add any dependencies' handles in here
    $ver = false; // you can leave this false, or define your own version #
    $in_footer = true; // if you want to load it in the footer
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
}
```

Then your Google Analytics script will load as part of your site's footer.